# The running time of an simple recursion algrithom

Tags: recursion

I knew how to solve this but I forget after many years. Here's the problem:

`T(n)` is the running time of an algorithm, and `T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n-2)`.
T(1) and T(2) takes constant running time.

What's the running time of `T(n)`?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/solving-recurrence-equations-containing-two-recursion-calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you implement it. If you store the result of `T(n)` in a table, you can run in linear time. If not, it will take exponential time. (Exponential in `n`.) (See wikipedia entry on [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).)